# How to make the program to be able to write to own executable at runtime?

Tags: c#, c++, portable-executable

I want to replace or add some bytes in my executable, **without using secondary writers after my program is closed**.
I know, usually this is impossible to do, but if this is needed?

I know a program called Unlocker, which is able to delete files currently in use or even running. It deletes blocking descriptors somehow. I think it injects own DLL into every running process.

So, if it inject own DLL into everything and somehow deletes blocking descriptors, maybe I can do same thing for own executable file? At least, I don't need to inject anything to program, because I developed it.

The solution could be in C / C++ also, I just DLL import needed function from own DLL.

Comment: Are you planning on running this application on PC's with AntiVirus programs installed?

Comment: Yes :O P.S. Unlocker somehow avoids to get punished.

Comment: You can easily open an exe file using FileStream then edit it with a BinaryWriter. However, even if you can do that, you'd need to know the portable executable format that exes are stored in to know what you were doing. As for editing programs as they are running, it's possible by obtaining their process, then invoking Windows core functions to obtain the entry point for process's code, but even if you manage that, you'd have to know how the process is laid out and you'd have to know machine code to be able to make any proper edits.

Comment: You could start the second process, which will modify your original executable. But what is the goal?

Comment: How second process can modify exe currently running? The goal is applying license, kind of program activation mechanism

Comment: @Kosmos: hmm... I thought, that this phrase "after my program is closed" means, that you want to modify exe after closing.

Comment: "without using secondary writers after my program is closed" ehm, this all together :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do something often is not to do it, but just pretend you did it.

For instance, when claiming to delete a file, it is often far easier to just move it to another directory on the same disk. That's just a matter of copying the metadata (directory entry) over.

Use that lesson: to "change" your executable, rename it (allowed while running), copy it back to its original name (officially a new file, not in use), and change the new file with the old name.

Comment: Thanks. This is kind of not the answer on the question, but since there is no any others and this is still can be used: +1 and accepted